# Cockpit cms 404 redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, cpanel, cockpit-cms

My website is hosted over `cpanel`: http://123.22.111.33/~folder/

When I try to access cockpit cms: http://123.22.111.33/~folder/cockpit

I've got 404 error, but URL is changed to: http://123.22.111.33/auth/login

I have rewrite rules, but they are not working properly.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

These settings are working on different domains, where cockpit is placed in root folder and not hosted over `cpanel`. This error redirect is probably caused by "`~`" character.